# Integer expression expected, SAP HANA stop script

Tags: bash, hana

I'm currently building a bash script to stop our SAP HANA database and afterwards check if it suceeded in stopping it. It's a work in progress and also my first "longer" script I've written.

For some reason it tells me:

> testscript.sh: line 19: [: : integer expression expected

why could this be?
Please have a look at my script below

```
#### errocodes
#### 0  hanadb state = OK
#### 10 hanadb state = STOPPED
#### 20 hanadb state = WARNING
#### 30 hanadb state = ERROR

# stop HANA DB
sudo /usr/sap/hostctrl/exe/sapcontrol -nr 00 -function Stop

# check hana db state
echo "Checking if Service is active"
HANADBSTATUS=`sudo /usr/sap/hostctrl/exe/sapcontrol -nr 00 -function GetProcessList`
if [ "$HANADBSTATUS" = GRAY ]
then
    echo "Hana DB is stopped."
    exit 10
else
    sleep 5
    while [ "$HANADBSTATUS" != GRAY ] && [ "$i" -lt 4 ]
        do
            echo "Warning: There seems to be a problem with stopping the HANA DB. Will retry 3-Times until Script will abort. This is retry Number: $i" 
            sudo /usr/sap/hostctrl/exe/sapcontrol -nr 00 -function Stop
            sleep 20
            HANADBSTATUS=`sudo /usr/sap/hostctrl/exe/sapcontrol -nr 00 -function GetProcessList`
            ((i++))
            if [ "$i" = 3 ]
                then
                    echo "Error: retried 3-Times. Couldn't stop DB. Exiting Script."
                    echo "Script aborts with Error 0"
                    exit 0
            fi
        done
    fi
```

Comment: Have you tried `set -x` for debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `set -x` (enable debug mode) after `sudo ...`, run the script, and review the debug output.

My guess is this - `[ "$i" -lt 4 ]` - is generating the error because the variable `i` is (initially) undefined so the test becomes `[ "" -lt 4 ]` which generates the same error you're seeing:

```
$ typeset -p i
-bash: typeset: i: not found

$ if [ "$i" -lt 4 ]; then echo yes;fi
-bash: [: : integer expression expected
```

Enabling debug mode to show what the test looks like with an undefined `i`:

```
$ set -x

$ if [ "$i" -lt 4 ]; then echo yes;fi
+ '[' '' -lt 4 ']'
-bash: [: : integer expression expected
```

One quick fix would be to insure `i` is initialized prior to the `while` loop, eg:

```
sleep 5
i=0

while [ "$HANADBSTATUS" != GRAY ] && [ "$i" -lt 4 ]
do
    ....
done
```

Comment: you're right! stupid me forgot to define i 